# lazy Filtering QTreeview with QsortFIlterProxymodel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I want to extend a question I asked earlier with a filter. In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46778623/lazy-loading-child-items-qtreeview)
I got help in lazy loading the treeview, parents first and only adding the parent's children when the user clicks on the node more or less as follows

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.mytreeview = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.mytreeview)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.mytreeview)
        self.mytreeview.setModel(self.model)
        self.mytreeview.clicked.connect(self.update_model)
        self.initialise_model()

    def initialise_model(self):
        for text in ["parent1", "parent2", "parent3"]:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

    def update_model(self, index):
        parent = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
        for text in ["children1", "children2", "children3"]:
            children = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}_{}".format(parent.text(), text))
            parent.appendRow(children)
        self.mytreeview.expand(index)
```

I now want to extend and make use of a filter for the treeview, so that a user can type in the name of a parent node and the treeview will filter itself down to the appropriate relevant nodes. I still want to keep the ability for the user to click on a parent node and even when filtered only then would the child nodes be added to the parent.

How can i adapt the following to do so? I have set the treeview up as follows

```
proxyModel = QSortFilterProxyModel(treeView)
proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)

# set model
treeView.setModel(proxyModel);   
treeView.setSortingEnabled(true)

def update_model(self, index):
    parent = self.model.itemFromIndex(index)
    ##not sure about this now in the light of the proxyModel
    for text in ["children1", "children2", "children3"]:
        children = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}_{}".format(parent.text(), text))
        parent.appendRow(children)
    self.mytreeview.expand(index)#not sure about this either as the index is of the proxyModel
```

I have two main questions firstly the proxyModel Index and the source model index, I am not sure how this works and also when expanding the clicked on node,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes that inherit from `QAbstractProxyModel` as `QSortFilterProxyModel` have the `mapToSource()` method that returns the index of the source model passing the index of the proxy model, also has another method called `mapFromSource()` that does the inverse so you must use that method to be able to add the items to the correct model.

To filter the data I added a `QLineEdit` where the `textChanged` signal is connected, the text that provides the signal we used for the filter.

```
class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.filterLe = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.mytreeview = QtGui.QTreeView(self)
        self.setLayout(QtGui.QVBoxLayout())
        self.layout().addWidget(self.filterLe)
        self.layout().addWidget(self.mytreeview)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.mytreeview)

        self.proxyModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self.mytreeview)
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.model)
        self.mytreeview.setSortingEnabled(True)

        # set model
        self.mytreeview.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.mytreeview.clicked.connect(self.update_model)
        self.filterLe.textChanged.connect(self.onTextChanged)
        self.initialise_model()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def onTextChanged(self, text):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(text)

    def initialise_model(self):
        for text in ["parent1", "parent2", "parent3"]:
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(text)
            self.model.appendRow(item)

    def update_model(self, index):
        ix = self.proxyModel.mapToSource(index)
        parent = self.model.itemFromIndex(ix)
        for text in ["children1", "children2", "children3"]:
            children = QtGui.QStandardItem("{}_{}".format(parent.text(), text))
            parent.appendRow(children)
        self.mytreeview.expand(index)
```

Comment: does it work with child items? I use the same approach but for some reason when I enter a child item name in the search field it is not found, but a parent item is ok

Comment: @SergeyMaslov QSortFilterProxyModel only works for parents, if you want to do a recusive filtering, use recursiveFilteringEnabled http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#recursiveFilteringEnabled-prop, 
But it is available only from PyQt 5.10